# Lock screen from a service

Tags: android

I want to lock the screen through a service, The service will be invoked depending upon the behavior of a broadcast receiver, It is successfully unlocking the activity,Now is it possible to lock screen from service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application contains a registered `DeviceAdminReceiver`, and the user has enabled your app via Settings to be a device admin, you can use `DevicePolicyManager` and `lockNow()` to lock the device.